# Home router with "advanced" firewall rules, only allow certain outbound IP ranges for specific devices

Tags: networking, router, firewall

I'm looking for a home network router that allows me to isolate certain machines from most of the internet but not all of it.  I donot want to do this based on port numbers alone but by ip range.

For example, a Windows 10 machine on my network (192.168.4.10) can communicate through a proxy, but also has need of accessing the internet in ways that cannot be proxied.  For this purpose, the box is allowed to connect to a specific IP range only (a.b.c.d/16 for example).  It would also be good if this can be either allow or deny based rules (some boxes only have deny rules, meaning you have to invert everything and cannot combine rules properly).

So I'd like to configure a rule in the router that looks like this (with `iptables`):

```
iptables -N PROXY   # create proxy chain
iptables -A FORWARD --source 192.168.4.10 -j PROXY    # send traffic from isolated machine to PROXY chain
iptables -A PROXY --destination 145.x.y.z/16 -j ACCEPT   # allow some subnet only
iptables -A PROXY -j DROP  # drop everything else (enforces proxy use)
```

Or shorter (untested):

```
iptables -A OUTPUT --source 192.168.4.10 --destination 145.x.y.z/16 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT --source 192.168.4.10 -j DROP
```

What router brand/type might have such capabilities, or what keyword should I be looking for?  Most I've looked at only allow this kind of blocking for a specific client based on "services" (ie. a port range and protocol).  If they'd also have some fields for an ip mask and make the ports optional I think it would be good enough for what I'm trying to achieve.

Any ideas?